# Test vectors for ECB, CBC, CFB and OFB modes of Triple DES

Tags: testing, encryption, standards, des, tripledes

Where I can get test vectors for CBC, CFB and OFB modes of Triple DES?

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-20/800-20.pdf) is NIST's document specifying the modes of operation for 3-DES. It includes test vectors.

Comment: Thanks for this link, but it is not what I need.
It would be very good if I found TV represented like this.
Plaintext:
12ad3135abf4e13
Ciphertext:
45fdae45901234d

Comment: Those test vectors are for 3DES-EDE1, which is pretty much DES. See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/21011/4520 . So in-so-far as test vectors go they're kinda weak.